# Can I get Minecraft Bedrock Edition to work on Windows 8?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, windows-8

I am forced to play on Java edition because our computers won't go past Windows 8. Is there any way to get the Bedrock features such as commands and game mechanics on Windows 8? Maybe a mod or something like that. i really want this to work.

Comment: What specific feature exists in Bedrock Edition that you feel is missing in Java Edition?

Comment: /Testfor and /tag are in Java

Comment: Even in Bedrock Edition, it's very rare that `testfor` is the right command to use, so I'm going to be perfectly clear on this point: **Don't use `testfor` for anything other than debug testing!** With that said, there's nothing that you could do with `testfor` or `tag` that you can't do with current commands, and more often than not, it'll be easier and run faster with the new commands.

Comment: I am mainly just more comfortable with bedrock because that's what I use at home on my Xbox. I'm not too sure how to use a lot of java features and was just wondering if there was a way I could make it easier for myself. The reason I need these commands is because In my computer tech class I convinced my teacher to let us use minecraft if we wanted instead of scratch. I had to go to an old version for testfor because I don't really understand the execute command that well, and in that update I don't think that the tag command was there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tag`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/tag) is available in Java Edition.

Syntax:

- `tag <targets> add <name>`
- `tag <targets> list`
- `tag <targets> remove <name>`

`testfor` can be replaced with the improved [`execute`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute) from 1.13. Instead of doing `testfor <targets>` in a command block with a comparator to activate another command, you can run `execute if entity <targets> run <some command>`.

Comment: Does this also work on a repeat command block testing for blocks instead of entities, or using [r=x] for players?

Comment: Update: I researched the execute command a bit more and it's a lot less confusing, but I still don't know how to make it so if I place a block somewhere something happens. It's gonna be a big learning curve, especially since even red stone is different, but I'm trying my best ;P but if there is still some way I can get bedrock that would still be easier

Comment: @Nightmare09122 To run a command if a block is `some_block`: `execute if block <pos> some_block run <some command>`